# VisualStudioOnline-Fxxxx resource group in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have resource grooup with this name : 'VisualStudioOnline-Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' type is 'Azure DevOps organization'. Is it used by Azure DevOps for billing ? I could not see this entry in pricing either.  Can I delete it?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is from setup billing for a new Azure Oganization. If you keep it no cost is charged as there are no resources. If you create resources in it yourself then it will come in cost analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the cost of the resource group in the **Cost analysis** of Cost Management to see if this resource group is used by Azure DevOps uses for billing.

[image]

Comment: It is not used. What if there is no cost to be billed for devops? Is this rg created by Azure Devops?

Comment: According to this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/563148/unexpected-name-of-resource-group-after-setup-bill.html) , when we linked the billing subscription to the organization from azure devops. Under the azure portal, the new resource group is named like `VisualStudioOnline-YYYYYY`.